# Where to download Synology DS214se DSM version 5.0?

Tags: nas, synology, synology-diskstation

I have recently connected my NAS DS214se back to internet after several years of not using it. I had to reset my NAS since it wouldn't let me to log in (not authorized). Current version of DSM software is 4.3 and I would like to install 7.1 to it. But it seems it can't skip a generation of OS and needs to update to 5.0 first.

If I try and install 6.2 and higher (manual update) it returns field value invalid. It also cant auto update since older versions of DSM have been discontinued.

Is there a way to install latest DSM directly or does anyone have any idea where can I find DSM 5 version for my NAS server? On DSM 4.3 Synology disk or client don't work properly with `QuickConnect_ID`.

Comment: You are likely out of luck.  [Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/status/EOL-announcement-for-legacy-dsm) has specifically remove older versions of DSM from it's website. So you would be stuck trying to find a random website that does have it, which of course, is not something anyone here should recommend. Your problem more complicate than you realize since you would need all versions between your current version and DSM 5.2-5967 in order to just get to a point where DSM 6.2.4 can be installed. You can reach out to Synology but you likely will be told "tough cookies",

Comment: See https://gizarena.com/how-to-safely-update-your-synology-nas-to-dsm-7/. As @Ramhound states, v. 6.24 appears to be the oldest at Synology, though, so without source for v. DSM 2.3-1157, DSM 3.1-1748, DSM 3.2-1955, DSM 4.0-2228, and DSM 4.3-3776, you're out of luck. BTW, Ubuntu has done a similar disservice to 32-bit users: you can install v. 16 and upgrade to 18.04, but there is no v. 18 installer. At lease 16 is still available online, though. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

The following website reports on Synology's discontinuation of support for their old software, starting on May 1, 2023. You can no longer access previous versions of DSM from the download site or their archive website.
https://www.blackvoid.club/end-of-availability-notice-for-legacy-dsm-surveillance-station-srm-and-more/

However, the second comment in the article mentions an important point: archive.org contains an earlier version of Synology's archive website, where you can download old versions of DSM: https://web.archive.org/web/20230510164622/https://archive.synology.com/download/Os/DSM

Therefore, for the DS214SE, you can download DSM 5.2-5967 at the following address: https://web.archive.org/web/20230510165323/https://global.synologydownload.com/download/DSM/release/5.2/5967/DSM_DS214se_5967.pat